# Materialize CSS sidenav is not clickable on mobile but works on desktop browser

Tags: html, css, materialize

Materialize CSS Sidenav works on desktop browser: the sidebar shows up when clicked. But when I tested it on the mobile browser, the menu icon shows, but when clicked it does not open the side bar. The html/css source is given below:

```
<nav class="white">
  <div class="nav-wrapper" >
    <a href="/" class="brand-logo center">
        <img src="/images/brand.png" width="150"/>
    </a>
    <a data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger">
        <i class="large material-icons cyan-text text-darken-4">menu</i>
    </a>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
            <li>
                <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                    <li>
                        <a class="collapsible-header">Login<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/users/login">Employer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/users/login">Job Seeker</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and the js init source is

```
 $('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDolF.png)

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: @midnightgamer v1.0.0-rc.1

Comment: can you please add a screenshot with sidenav

Comment: @midnightgamer I've updated the question to include the screenshot

Comment: try to copy and past code from documentation

Comment: @midnightgamer I tried the code from the documentation and it works. Thanks. I've now going to modify it to reflect the changes

Comment: Okay ! always try using documentation code first.

Comment: @midnightgamer do you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @midnightgamer Thanks for the tip! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy code from documentation and modify according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try zIndex=1 to sidenav and nav class